# How can i create a div without side spaces?

Tags: html, css

I don't know why side spaces are not eliminated if the div's position is not set to "fixed" and when using bootstrap framework, the side spaces are eliminated automatically.
I've created this HTML page and I'd like to know how to do that.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
     <title> No side Spaces Div</title>

     <style>

     #navigation {
     background-color:#CECECE;
     color:#545454;
     font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size:18px;
     padding:12px;
     }

     #content {
     background-color:#EAEAEA;
     font-size:16px;
     }

     a:link, a:visited {
     color:inherit;
     padding:inherit;
     text-decoration:none;
     }

     a:hover, a:active {
     color:#030303;
     }

    </style>
 </head>

    <body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        This is some text...
    </div>

</html>
```

Comment: It's the browsers default padding being applied to the `body` tag. You might want to consider looking into a reset css - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Stuff like this is btw. pretty easy to find out using the developer tools that every modern browser has build in – so I suggest you go familiarize yourself with them.

Answer (score 1):

set the margin and padding to zero:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, browser adds margin and padding to the elements. You need to reset it using the following CSS snippet.

```css
* { /* I suggest body element for your solution */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>No side Spaces Div</title>

  <style>
    #navigation {
      background-color: #CECECE;
      color: #545454;
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 12px;
    }
    #content {
      background-color: #EAEAEA;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    a:link,
    a:visited {
      color: inherit;
      padding: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover,
    a:active {
      color: #030303;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navigation">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    This is some text...
  </div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS reset like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0ranu5h4/)**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

For full CSS reset **[This link](http://cssreset.com/)** will be helpful.

**Update:**

> A CSS Reset (or “Reset CSS”) is a short, often compressed (minified)
>   set of CSS rules that resets the styling of all HTML elements to a
>   consistent baseline.

For more info go through this **[link](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)**

Comment: can't i do anything on my own?

Comment: means, what you want to do? I dont get you?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand what you did

Answer (score -1):

try this in your css;

```
body {
   margin :0;
   padding :0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you add a duplicate answer, with even less explanation, and terrible formatting, more than ten minutes after everyone else?